# how do I display different content from database on one php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I am trying to use one php file `php.project` and depending on the name of 1 variable I get all the data from the database that is needed and display it on the site. Right now I have one problem.

I have one php file that is this:

```
<?php

$pName = $_POST['name'];
$db_connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',"project_online_planner");
if (!$db_connection){
    die('Failed to connect to MySql:'.mysql_error());
}

//insert into database
if(isset($_POST['insertComments'])){
    include('connect-mysql.php');
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO user_comments (username, comment, project) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$pName')";
        if (!mysqli_query($db_connection, $sqlinsert)){
            die('error inserting new record');
        }
        else{
            $newRecord = "1 record added";
        }//end nested statement

}

//text from database
$query="SELECT * FROM user_comments where project = '$pName' ";
$results = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query);
$intro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

$query2="SELECT * FROM project where name = '$pName' ";
$results2 = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query2);
$intro2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2);


?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project planner online</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/ppo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/ppo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="intro">

</div>
<div id="bgNav">
    <nav id="nav">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a class="rightNav" href="register.php">Register</a>
        <a class="rightNav" href="login.php">Log in</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="projectTile">
    <span id="statusCheck"><?php print_r($intro2["status"]); ?></span>
    <h2 id="prTitle"><?php print_r($intro2["name"]); ?></h2>
<div id="prPic"><img width="300" height="200" src="<?php print_r($intro2["image"]); ?>"></div>
<div id="prDescription"><?php print_r($intro2["description"]); ?></div>
</div>
<div id="comments">
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        echo nl2br("<div class='profile_comments'>" . $row['username'] . "</div>");
        echo nl2br("<div class='comment_comments'>" . $row['comment'] . "</div>");
    }
    ?>

</div>

<div id="uploadComments">
    <form method="post" action="project.php">
        <label for="name"><input type="hidden" name="insertComments" value="true"></label>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>comment</legend>
        <label>Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="username" value=""></label><br/>
        <label>Comments: <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitComment">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

depending on the variable  `$pName` the content of the site changes, because it gets its content from a database and `$pName` stands for "project name".

```
$pName is determenent by the name of the picture you click on the index page which is this:

<?php   

$db_connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',"project_online_planner");
if (!$db_connection){
    die('Failed to connect to MySql:'.mysql_error());
}
$query="SELECT * FROM project limit 5 ";
$results = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query);
$intro=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project planner online</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/ppo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/ppo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bgNav">
    <div id="login">
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
        <a href="login.php">Log in</a>
    </div>

    <nav id="nav">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </nav>
</div>
<h2 class="titlePage">Home</h2>
<div id="bgTile">
    <?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $project = $row["name"];
        echo nl2br("<img id=\"$project\" width='100px' alt='Procject name' height='100px' class='tile' src=". $row['image'] ."/>");
    }
    ?>

    <a href="allprojects.php"><div class="tile" id="tileM"><h2>Meer</h2></div></a>

</div>
    <form action="project.php" method="post" id="formF">
        <label><input id="inputF" type="hidden" name="name"></label><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

by clicking the image I put the name of it in a form and submit it to project.php. in project. php it is stored in the variable `$pName` . The problem is that once I refresh the page the `$pName` becomes `Null` and you see none of the database's data on the page. my question is: how can change this code in a way that `$pName` doesn't become `Null` when I refresh the page? and are there any suggestions on how to improve this code?

this is my javascript:

```
var check = null;
var form = $('#myForm');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){

        $('#inputF').val(this.id);
        $("input[type=submit]").trigger("click");
    });
});
```

Comment: _"I am trying to use one php file "php.project"..."_. Shouldn't it be `project.php`?

Comment: Read about PHP sessions. http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: store the name in a session variable, and check, `if(!isset($_POST['name'])){ use session instead }` for erxample

Comment: You have an sql injection problem. You should read up on prepared statements.

Comment: @lorenzo456 i think my answer was pretty helpfull. please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: @AndreschSerj Sorry I forgot to accept this as my answer. This did Solve my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Sessions to you code (as requested by @aleation).
Also, using parameters directly to query your database is very dangerous (as @jeroen mentioned).
Read up on the topic of [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and try to evaluate $pName before using it in a query.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!is_null($_POST['name']))
{ 
  $pName = $_POST['name'];
  $_SESSION['pName'] = $pName;
}
elseif (array_key_exists('pName',$_SESSION)) {
  $pName = $_SESSION['pName'];
}
else {
  $pName = ''; // Maybe set a default here?
}

$pName = $_POST['name'];
$db_connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','',"project_online_planner");
if (!$db_connection){
 die('Failed to connect to MySql:'.mysql_error());
}
...
```

Tiny glimpse into the Problem SQL Injections bring: In your example, imagine someone send's a POST request where name is `';Delete FROM project where id <>`.
This would result in you loosing all your entries in the project table. 
And that Query injection wouldn't even be that hard to guess.
With analyzing your website, someone could get hold of userdata, manipulate userdata, insert userdata ... you see? It is a mess.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading up on it now and my code works exactly how I want it to. and thanks for the extra suggestions, really helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a $_POST variable for selecting the right content? If you make your images hyperlinks with the project name in the address, you can refresh the page without losing the variable content.

change:

```
echo nl2br("<img id=\"$project\" width='100px' alt='Procject name' height='100px' class='tile' src=". $row['image'] ."/>");
```

into

```
echo nl2br("<a href=\"project.php?name=$project\"><img id=\"$project\" width='100px' alt='Project name' height='100px' class='tile' src=".$row['image']."/></a>");
```

and then get $pname = $_GET['name'] instead of $pname = $_POST['name']